# Find if there's a close enough node to the end node (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

```
def explorer(visited, graph, node, N, M, K):
    if ((node[0]-N)**2+(node[1]-M)**2)**(1/2) <= K:
        return True
    if node not in visited:
        visited.append(node)
        for element in graph:
            if ((node[0]-element[0])**2+(node[1]-element[1])**2)**(1/2) <= K:
                if ((element[0]-N)**2+abs(element[1]-M)**2)**(1/2)<=K:
                        visited.append(element)
                        return True
                return explorer(visited, graph, element, N, M, K)
```

I'm using the aforementioned function over a list of nodes, which I know has a path from [0,0] to [N, M]. But the function returns None.

Comment: What? Does it not exit? Or does it return `True` or `None`?

Comment: It returns None

Comment: So either the `for` loop exits or it calls `explorer(...`, but you meant to write `return explorer(...`.

Comment: I suggest you start to explain in your question why do you expect the function to return True on an example of parameter you passed to it. On the path to the explanation you will then see yourself where your expectation goes wrong and this way you get your question answered by yourself. By the way: in Python the function returns None if it exits (after executing all its code) without running into an explicit return value statement, like the following function: `def f(): pass ` which also returns None.